# Digital pH Tester - fish tank

Tags: aquarium, fish, freshwater, equipment

Is there any digital pH tester on the market at all? I've done a search around and pet-stores and the usual companies (Fluval, API, etc) don't sell them as far as I can tell. Some companies I don't recognize do sell something like this. I could be imagining it, but I seem to remember a tool in a school physics class that tested pH. I seem to remember two metal rods in the water connected to a device that measured the pH.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Cormac.

Comment: Hi welcome to Pets, yes you remember correctly that a device like this exists, it consists of two electrodes where one of them is submerged in the solution that is being tested, it creates an electric potential that is interpreted by the meter and translated into a pH reading; they are definitely being commonly used in laboratories but I've never seen them in any aquarist shop where I live, but on the Internet I see there are meters for aquarium use as well.

Comment: you can take a look here https://aquariumadviser.com/best-ph-meters/ i have never used any of them so i do not know how good they are.